# How to display a matplotlib figure object

Tags: python, matplotlib, figures

I am working with a matplotlib-based routine that returns a figure and, as separate objects, the axes that it contains.  Is there any way, that I can display these things and edit them (annotate, change some font sizes, things like that)?  "fig.show()" doesn't work, just returns an error.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an interactive backend?  If you have the objects you can use the full OO interface on them.

Comment: Can you show us your code and the error?

Answer (score 0):

Figures need a canvas to draw on.

Try fig.draw()